# C++ templates with friend function and operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

I have been adding c++ templates to an existing Operator overloading program, and now I'm getting these errors.
I'm not able to rectify these errors, can anybody help me...
Here's the code...
I'm able to template on simple overloaded function but having problem on friend function..
*****************NOTE:(Updated)
Code after Rectification...
    /*PROGRAM TO DEMONSTRATE OPERATOR OVERLOADING*/
    #include

```
template <class T>
class OP 
{
    T x, y, z;

    public:

    void IN()
    {
        std::cout << "Enter three No's : ";
        std::cin >> x >> y >> z;
    }

    void OUT()
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << x << " " << y << " " << z;
    }
    void operator~();
    void operator+(int);                    //Can accept both one or two argument

    template<class TA>
    friend void operator++(OP<T>);             //Accept one arguments (Unary Operator);

    template<class TB>
    friend void operator-(OP<T>, int);     //Accept two arguments     (Binary Operator)

    template<class TC>
    friend void operator!=(OP&, char t);
};

template<class T>
void OP<T>::operator~() //Unary Member Operator
{
    std::cout << std::endl << " ~ (tilde)";
}

template<class T>
void OP<T>::operator+(int y)    //Binary Member Operator
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Argument sent is " << y;
}

template<class T>
void operator-(OP<T> &a, int t) //Binary Friend Operator
{
    a.x= a.x-t;
    a.y= a.y-t;
    a.z= a.z-t;
}

template<class T>
void operator!=(OP<T> &q, char t)   //Binary Friend Operator
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Char " << t; 
}

template<class T>
void operator++(OP<T> x)    //Unary Friend Operator
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Friend Unary Operator";
}

int main()
{
    OP <int> n, m;
    n.IN();
    m.IN();
    m+1;
    n!='t';
    int a = 1;
    char r='r';
    ~n;         //Member Function (Unary)
    n-a;        //Member Function (Unary)
    operator-(m, a);    //Friend Function (Binary)
    operator++(m);  //Friend Function (Unary)
    n.OUT();
    m.OUT();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is on all three friend function and the error is

> > > Now my friend function is not able to access the private member...<<<
> > >       Please tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a friend function within a *template* class, you must either provide the definition within the template class definition, or redeclare it outside the template class.

Declaring it as a friend with in the template class does not declare that function in the enclosing scope.

Comment: Thanks, using first solution has solved the problem but can you tell me how to redeclare it outside the class..

Comment: Declare the function before declaring the template with the friend statement in it - same as defining the function but without the body. Of course you'll need to forward-declare the template class before you declare a function that uses the class as an argument.